# Continue add selected php in large value

Tags: notepad++, php, regex, find-and-replace, sublime-text-2

I have a large amount of code in notepad++ or any editor but I want to replace all the text quickly.

Is there any option edit and replace in notepad++?

```
                        <option value="0"       <?php if($options=="PHP") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Min Price</option>
                        <option value="25000"   <?php if($options=="PHP") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>25,000</option>
                        <option value="50000"   <?php if($options=="PHP") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>50,000</option>
                        <option value="75000"   <?php if($options=="PHP") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>75,000</option>
                        <option value="100000"  <?php if($options=="PHP") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>100,000</option>
                        <option value="125000">125,000</option>
                        <option value="150000">150,000</option>
                        <option value="175000">175,000</option>
                        <option value="200000">200,000</option>
                        <option value="225000">225,000</option>
                        -------
                        -------
                        -------
                        -------
                        -------
                        ----etc---
```

How to add php echo selected like 1st 4 value in on all other values easily.
Note: I don't want Loop. (I'm using Notepad++ or Sublime Editor)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, you add `selected` attribute to **ALL** options when `$options=="PHP"`. What are you trying to do with this code? To answer your question: Yes, it is possible to modify all the lines, but you have to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you forego your XY-problem (turd-polishing task), scrap the non-D.R.Y. code, and use a loop fed a range of values.  As you iterate, conditionally inject the `selected` attribute using whatever conditional logic is appropriate for your application.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IZuaH))

```
$selectedNumber = 75000;

echo '<option value="0">Min Price</option>';
foreach (range(25000, 200000, 25000) as $number) {
    printf(
        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
        $number,
        $number == $selectedNumber ? ' selected' : '',
        number_format($number)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
<option value="0">Min Price</option>
<option value="25000">25,000</option>
<option value="50000">50,000</option>
<option value="75000" selected>75,000</option>
<option value="100000">100,000</option>
<option value="125000">125,000</option>
<option value="150000">150,000</option>
<option value="175000">175,000</option>
<option value="200000">200,000</option>
```

---

If you want to keep your bloated/W.E.T. script the way it is, you can highlight all of the targeted options tags in the select and:

find: `(<option value=")(\d+)(")`
replace: `$1$2$3<?php echo \$selectedNumber == "$2" ? ' selected' : ''; ?>`

---

I don't use sublime (or notepad++ anymore), but on PHPStorm you could use the same find pattern, then click "Select All Occurrences" (<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Shft-J</kbd>), then press the right arrow on your keyword (which will un-highlight the matched characters and place carets at the end of the matches), then just start typing what you want if you don't want dynamic text on each line -- but that part of your question (as @Toto pointed out) makes no logical sense.